# Using enum as key in CollectorsToMap, Java StreamAPI

Tags: java

I have an interface with a method and supported types

```
interface PropertyEvaluator{
 Collection<Type> getSupportedType();

public enum Type
    {
        NAME, STATE, CODE
    }
}
```

I also have two implementations of this interface:

Implementation1:

```
class FieldPropertyEvaluator implements PropertyGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Collection<Type> getSupportedType()
    {
        return Set.of(Type.NAME, Type.STATE);
    }
}
```

Implementation2:

```
class CodePropertyEvaluator implements PropertyGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Collection<Type> getSupportedType()
    {
        return Set.of(Type.CODE);
    }
}
```

In service classA, I need to build a map which will store properyType as key and class name as values

```
 public classA
 {
   private final Map<PropertyEvaluator.Type, PropertyEvaluator> propertyEvaluatorMap = null;
   
   public void ClassA(Collection<PropertyEvaluator> propertyEvaluators)
   {
     //this is where I am stuck, I could go thus far, but I am getting an error that PropertyEvaluator.Type is not allowed
     propertyEvaluatorMap = 
propertyEvaluators.stream().flatMap(propertyEvaluator -> 
                            propertyEvaluators.getSupportedType()
                            .stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(PropertyEvaluator.Type, 
                                                      Function.identity()));
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you declare `Map<PropertyEvaluator.Type, PropertyEvaluator> propertyEvaluatorMap`, does it mean that no two implementations of the interface will ever be related to the same `Type`?

Comment: Yes. That's correct, in other words, each type will correspond to a single Implementation as the list grows in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep reference of type to evaluator - which is done here by creating new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<> with such information.
Also you need to be aware that such approach will work if there will be no duplicates of types across all evaluators.

```
public Map<PropertyEvaluator.Type, PropertyEvaluator> getPropertyEvaluators(Collection<PropertyEvaluator> propertyEvaluators) {
    return propertyEvaluators.stream()
            .flatMap(propertyEvaluator -> propertyEvaluator.getSupportedType().stream().map(type -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(type, propertyEvaluator)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: syntax sugar to create map entry:<br/>


`propertyEvaluatorMap = propertyEvaluators.stream()
                                                 .flatMap(propertyEvaluator -> propertyEvaluator.getSupportedType().stream().map(type -> Map.entry(type, propertyEvaluator)))
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));`